# View not updating when it's properties change in custom delegate

Tags: objective-c, uiviewanimation

I have an ACPDownloadView instance of AppDelegate. It's showing downloading progress. When I update it's progress value in my view controller, it works fine.

```
appdelegate.downloadVew=[[ACPDownloadView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];
appdelegate.downloadVew.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
progressBtn= [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:appdelegate.downloadVew];
ACPIndeterminateGoogleLayer * layer = [ACPIndeterminateGoogleLayer new];
[layer updateColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
[appdelegate.downloadVew setIndeterminateLayer:layer];
[appdelegate.downloadVew setIndicatorStatus:ACPDownloadStatusRunning];
[appdelegate.downloadVew setProgress:0.0 animated:NO];
```

Now, I have a delegate method which called when progress updated.

```
 -(void)progressAddChannel:(NSProgress *)uploadProgress{

      float prog=uploadProgress.fractionCompleted;

      [appdelegate.downloadVew setProgress:prog animated:YES];
     [appdelegate.downloadVew layoutIfNeeded];
     NSLog(@"%f",prog);
```

}

This code executes and show correct value of progress. But that progress is not animating on appdelegate.downloadVew. Do anyone know about this behavior?

Comment: Did you check if the code runs on main thread?

Comment: No I didn't. I'll check now. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was my issue. I was not calling this on MainThread.

Comment: Glad to be of help...I'll put this as an answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are making UI changes make sure your code runs on the main thread.